# On the proof of a result of Bayer and Stillman

Tags: commutative-algebra, homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, local-cohomology

I'm reading through the paper [A criterion for detecting m-regularity](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/download/pdf/PPN356556735_0087/LOG_0007.pdf) of Bayer and Stillmann and came across a proof, where I don't understand an implication.

The following things may need to be mentioned:

- $S = k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, $I \subset S$ is a homogeneous ideal and $M$ a graded $S$-module
- $\mathfrak{m}$ = $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ denotes the irrelevant maximal ideal of $S$
- $H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i}(M)_d$ will denote the degree $d$ part of the $i$-th local cohomology group of $M$
- $I$ is $m$-regular if $H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i}(I)_d = 0 $ for all $i$ and $d \geq m-i+1$.
- $I$ is $m$-saturated if $I^{\textit{sat}}_d = I_d$ for all $d \geq m$.
- $h \in S$ is called generic for $I$ if $h$ is not a zero-divisor on $S/I^{\textit{sat}}$

It concerns the following Lemma:

> Lemma 1.8: Let $I \subset S$ be an ideal, and suppose $h\in S_1$ is generic for $I$. TFAE:
>
> (a) $I$ is $m$-regular
>
> (b) $I$ is $m$-saturated, and $(I,h)$ is $m$-regular

The proof of the direction $(a)\implies(b)$ looks like this:

> *Proof.*
> Since $I$ is $m$-regular, it follows that $I$ is $m$-saturated by a previous remark (1.3 in paper). (Thus, it remains to be shown that $(I,h)$ is $m$-regular). 
> Let $Q = (I:h)/I$ to get an exact sequence
> \begin{equation}
> 0 \rightarrow I \rightarrow (I:h) \rightarrow Q \rightarrow 0.
> \end{equation}
> Since $I$ is $m$-saturated and $h$ generic for $I$, by a previous Lemma (1.6 in the paper) it follows that $I_d = (I:h)_d$ for all $d \geq m$ and therefore $\dim(Q) = 0.$ Thus, $H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i}(Q) = 0$ for $i \neq 0$, and $H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{0}(Q) = Q$. 
> Thus, by the long exact sequence for local cohomology we obtain
> \begin{equation}
> \tag{$\star$} H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i}(I)_d \cong H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i}((I:h))_d \text{ for } d \geq m -i+1 \text{ and all } i.
> \end{equation}
> Considering the exact sequence
> \begin{equation}
> 0 \rightarrow I \cap (h) \rightarrow I \oplus (h) \rightarrow (I,h) \rightarrow 0.
> \end{equation}
> and the fact that $I\cap(h) = (I:h)h$, we get
> \begin{equation}
> 0 \rightarrow (I:h)(-1) \rightarrow I\oplus(h) \rightarrow (I,h) \rightarrow 0,
> \end{equation}
> which leads to
> \begin{equation}
>  \tag{$\star \star$}H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i}(I\oplus(h))_d \rightarrow H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i}((I,h))_d\rightarrow H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i+1}((I:h))_{d-1}.
> \end{equation}

So far I think I can follow, but in the paper the proof gets concluded in the following way:

> From $(\star\star)$ and the isomorphism $(\star)$ it follows that $(I,h)$ is $m$-regular.

**Question:**
If I have that $H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i}((I,h))_d = 0 $ for all $i$ and $d \geq m-i+1$, then the conclusion follows by definition. However, I don't see how $(\star\star)$ and $(\star)$ imply this. 
Since $I$ is $m$-regular $H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i}(I)_d = H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i}((I:h))_d = 0 $ for all $i$ and $d \geq m-i+1$. But I think that is not enough to conclude the result.

What am I missing resp. why is the above enough to conclude the proof?

I'm rather unfamiliar with the concept of local cohomology, so the implication may be obvious, but I can't see it.

Comment: Hi. I think the strategy is to show the outer two components in the double star equation vanish in degrees we want. Then by the exactness, the middle one needs to vanish too. You already showed this for the 3rd component. For the first component, the local cohomology of a direct sum is the direct sum of the local cohomologies. $H^i_n(I)$ you already have this. Here $n$ is your mathfrak $m$. Since $h \in S_1$ and $S$ is a domain, $(h) \cong S(-1)$. I think $S$ is 0-regular, and this should imply that the required degrees to vanish for $S(-1)$.

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't aware of the fact that local cohomology commutes direct sums. But knowing that, it should work like this.

Comment: @Youngsu: I posted an answer based on your comment. I hope it's okay.

Comment: @ShiveringSoldier That's ok with me. These days it is hard for me to find time for stackexchange. I will go over your answer soon. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expanding on Youngsu's comment:

We have the isomorphism $$H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i}(I)_d \cong H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i}((I:h))_d \text{ for } d \geq m -i+1 \text{ and all } i\tag{$\star$}$$
and the exact sequence
$$H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i}(I\oplus(h))_d \rightarrow H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i}((I,h))_d\rightarrow H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i+1}((I:h))_{d-1}.$$
We need to show that
$H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i}((I,h))_d = 0 $ for $d \geq m-i+1$ and all $i$.

Notice that $H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i}(I\oplus(h))\cong H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i}(I)\oplus H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i}((h))$ (see for instance [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3765337/588038)). Next, we have $(h)\cong S(-1)$ as $S$-modules.
So,
\begin{align}
H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i}(I\oplus(h))_d
&=H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i}(I)_d\oplus H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i}(S(-1))_d\\
&=H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i}(I)_d\oplus H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i}(S)_{d-1}.\\
\end{align}
Recall that the local cohomologies of the polynomial ring $S=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is given by
$$H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i}(S)_d=\begin{cases}\operatorname{Hom}_k(S_{-n-d},k),&i=n\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
(see [[Eisenbud, Cor.10.9]](https://www.msri.org/people/staff/de/ready.pdf)).
Thus $H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i}(I\oplus(h))_d=0$ for  all $d\geq m-i+1$ and $i\neq n$. Suppose that $i=n$ and $d\geq m-n+1$. Then we have $$H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{n}(I\oplus(h))_d=H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{n}(I)_d\oplus H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{n}(S)_{d-1}=0\oplus \operatorname{Hom}_k(S_{-n-d+1},k).$$
Since $d\geq m-n+1$, we have $0\geq -m\geq -n-d+1$, so $S_{-n-d+1}=0$. Therefore, $H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{n}(I\oplus(h))_d=0$ for all $d\geq m-n+1$. Thus the left-hand term of the exact sequence vanishes for all $d\geq m-n+1$.

Finally, consider the right-hand term. For $d\geq m-i+1$, we have $d-1\geq m-(i+1)+1$, so  $H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i+1}((I:h))_{d-1}$ is isomorphic to $H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i+1}(I)_{d-1}$ by $(\star)$. As $I$ is $m$-regular, it follows that $H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i+1}((I:h))_{d-1}=0$ for all $d\geq m-i+1$. Hence the middle term $H_{\mathfrak{m}}^{i}((I,h))_d$ also vanishes for $d \geq m-i+1$ and all $i$.

Comment: nice argument!! (sorry to dredge up an old post; was looking at your profile and saw this question). the linked paper in OP's post looks interesting